# NinePatch Background and Android

Tags: android, textures, nine-patch

I am looking to add a Noisy Background in my android app. The texture is perfect and I can create a NinePatch image, but when I actually use it in the app it stretches causing lines throughout the background. Any idea what a better way would be to implement this type of texture?

I would also be looking to use something similar for the actionbar.

[image: NoisyGrey]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9-Patch will stretch, You have to specify which area should stretch in the image. Why dont you try repeating your drawable. like so:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/YourLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
>
```

then in an xml called backrepeat.xml

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```